# Re-syncing after git filter branch

Tags: git, git-filter-branch

I am splitting a part of the local large repository(x) into smaller repository(y). The pruning is done using git filter-branch and its formed into a smaller repository. Now that there are some new commits by others into the large repository(x). I would like to sync the new commits into my smaller repository also(which is formed by pruning using filter-branch).

Some queries that I had,

1. Once after the filter branch is done on a clone, can we do a git pull/fetch to retrieve the latest commits and then again do a filter branch ? In this case, will the filter branch only take prune the latest commit ?
2. Any idea how are we to sync the new commits by setting a daily job that would do the below

   - Retrieve the new commits
   - prune the new commits as per the ignore regex that we specified in the filter-branch
   - push the new changes to the smaller repository

thanks

-Shar

Comment: Oy #2 sounds like an M.C. Escher-esk nightmare. What problem are you trying to solve by croning filter branch? Splitting a large repository into sub-repos should be a one-time operation.

Comment: Christopher, instead of a one time operation, we are planning to create a smaller repository by pruning. Since pruning our large repository would take some 15-20 hours, the new commits to the large repository has to be synced to the smaller repository by respecting the filter specified. Another case is, once after we create the smaller repository, we would have our application first test with the smaller repository, until this testing phase the large repository would not be read-only. So the new commits have to be synced periodically to the small repository until the cut-off date.